# setInterval function cannot use outer variable

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

Why is prevColor always `undefined`?

This code should log a new color (`actualColor`) and the previous color (`prevColor`). However I cannot save into `prevColor` from inside the `setInterval` function. Where is the bug? I don´t think it is a context problem. But I´m not sure. There´s no `this` inside...

Can you tell me how I can save the value of `actualColor` in `prevColor` from inside the `setInterval` function?

```
var actualColor;
var prevColor;


// do some user action and change actualColor


setInterval(function () {
    // only log the color if it differs from prevColor
    if (actualColor != prevColor) {
        console.log("actualColor: " + actualColor + ", prevColor: " + prevColor);
    }
    prevColor = actualColor;
}, 100);
```

Console:

```
actualColor: acff06, prevColor: undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Where are you setting `actualColor`?

Comment: You don't give your variables any value.

Comment: I left this part out in this code snippet.  It would have been too long. There is a comment inside the code.

Comment: If i set a number to prevColor in line 2 the console will always log this value. But no updated Color

Comment: It appears to be working as expected given your code, what behaviour are you wanting? The first interval will log undefined because the value is set after the console.log, and the console won't log again because the values are now equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be your context -I made a simple webpage with all the bits you have above, and it works fine -even without setting initial values on the variables:

[image: simple page+console]

I placed your code in a script tag in the HEAD, and added

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="actualColor"
    />
<input
    type="button"
    onclick = "actualColor = document.getElementById('actualColor').value;"
    value = "change colour" />
```

to provide a way of changing actualColor in the webpage (rather than using the console)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the value of the `prevColor`, otherwise first time it will be `undefined`

Just do

```
var actualColor;
var prevColor = "";


// do some user action and change actualColor


setInterval(function () {
    // only log the color if it differs from prevColor
    if (actualColor != prevColor) {
        console.log("actualColor: " + actualColor + ", prevColor: " + prevColor);
    }
    prevColor = actualColor;
}, 100);
```